# How to connect phone to Android studio over 4G internet?

Tags: android, android-studio, remote-debugging

I want to connect my phone to Android studio running on my home PC over my phone cellular network 4G internet.

I've looked up the [ADB documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html) and saw that remote connection can be done if both the PC and the phone are on the same network so I'm guessing a solution would be to setup some kind of VPN. I'm wondering if there isn't anything simpler that can be done? Something as simple as an app or an Android Studio add-on that handles all the connections and security considerations would be nice.

Comment: Needs clarification. Chrome remote desktop will indeed let you view, point, click and type on your PC using your phone but this is quite different from using ADB.

Comment: you would usually use adb over network on wifi, because both adb and the device would run on the same network. On cellular, the issue is that your phone does not have a public ip, unless your provider gives you an ipv6?

Comment: create hotspot with your 4G and connect to it with your laptop? there are plenty of over-Wi-Fi ways :) if you are lucky you may have two wireless/ethernet modules for using internet connection from another source

Comment: @snachmsm not possible, my laptop and phone are a good 20 km apart hence why I can't use my home network. Wish I could just bring the laptop but that's also impossible so I'm kinda stuck